# c raw socket program works on desktop but not on laptop

Tags: c, sockets, raw-sockets

I wrote a c program which uses raw sockets to send a simple ARP request. I wrote this program on my desktop pc running Ubuntu LTS 16.04 and it works the way it is supposed to. Now I got a new laptop (ThinkPad t470) running Ubuntu 16.04, too. I copied the c file an compiled it on my laptop. When i run the program it seems to work just fine but doesn't send any packets. I watched he traffic with wireshark but there is nothing. The exact same program runs just fine on my desktop. Could there be a problem with the interface, on my desktop I use a lan connection and on my laptop a wlan? I can't seem to find why it is not sending any packets on my laptop. Help is really appreciated!

Thank you guys!

Comment: Are you running as root?

Comment: Yes. It doesn't even give me an error. The sendto() funcion returns the right size of the buffer to send but there are no outgoing packets on wireshark and my program doesnt receive an arp reply either.

Comment: Are you certain that you are sending the packet to the ethernet interface?  Just for kicks, run a sniffer on loopback and try it again.

Comment: Difference in firewall configuration perhaps?

Comment: Okay, I tried it on loopback but got nothing again. But I also tried it with a lan connction (ethernet cable) and now its working. Thank you guys for your time, espacially David Hoelzer your advice with the loopback brought up the idea of using the ethernet connection! I never really thought about it but I guess i missinderstood a bacis concept of networking. Is it possible to send an ethernet (+arp) frame over a wireless network with the ethernet protocol? or is that obly possible on (like the name says) an ethernet connection ? I guess I got that wrong.